# Why do I get "Error (el-get): while installing transient" when starting emacs?

Tags: emacs, el-get

I very suddenly starting experiencing a problem while loading emacs. Emacs now takes a very long time to load and when it does, I get the warnings:

```
Generating transient.info
make[1]: makeinfo: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [transient.info] Error 1
make: *** [info] Error 2
```

my init.el file contains:

```
(defvar current-user
  (getenv
   (if (equal system-type 'windows-nt) "USERNAME" "USER")))

(message "Prelude is powering up... Be patient, Master %s!" current-user)

(when (version< emacs-version "25.1")
  (error "Prelude requires GNU Emacs 25.1 or newer, but you're running %s" emacs-version))

;; Always load newest byte code
(setq load-prefer-newer t)

(defvar prelude-dir (file-name-directory load-file-name)
  "The root dir of the Emacs Prelude distribution.")
(defvar prelude-core-dir (expand-file-name "core" prelude-dir)
  "The home of Prelude's core functionality.")
(defvar prelude-modules-dir (expand-file-name  "modules" prelude-dir)
  "This directory houses all of the built-in Prelude modules.")
(defvar prelude-personal-dir (expand-file-name "personal" prelude-dir)
  "This directory is for your personal configuration.

Users of Emacs Prelude are encouraged to keep their personal configuration
changes in this directory.  All Emacs Lisp files there are loaded automatically
by Prelude.")
(defvar prelude-personal-preload-dir (expand-file-name "preload" prelude-personal-dir)
  "This directory is for your personal configuration, that you want loaded before Prelude.")
(defvar prelude-vendor-dir (expand-file-name "vendor" prelude-dir)
  "This directory houses packages that are not yet available in ELPA (or MELPA).")
(defvar prelude-savefile-dir (expand-file-name "savefile" prelude-dir)
  "This folder stores all the automatically generated save/history-files.")
(defvar prelude-modules-file (expand-file-name "prelude-modules.el" prelude-personal-dir)
  "This file contains a list of modules that will be loaded by Prelude.")
(defvar prelude-deprecated-modules-file
  (expand-file-name "prelude-modules.el" prelude-dir)
  (format "This file may contain a list of Prelude modules.

This is DEPRECATED, use %s instead." prelude-modules-file))

(unless (file-exists-p prelude-savefile-dir)
  (make-directory prelude-savefile-dir))

(defun prelude-add-subfolders-to-load-path (parent-dir)
 "Add all level PARENT-DIR subdirs to the `load-path'."
 (dolist (f (directory-files parent-dir))
   (let ((name (expand-file-name f parent-dir)))
     (when (and (file-directory-p name)
                (not (string-prefix-p "." f)))
       (add-to-list 'load-path name)
       (prelude-add-subfolders-to-load-path name)))))

;; add Prelude's directories to Emacs's `load-path'
(add-to-list 'load-path prelude-core-dir)
(add-to-list 'load-path prelude-modules-dir)
(add-to-list 'load-path prelude-vendor-dir)
(prelude-add-subfolders-to-load-path prelude-vendor-dir)

;; reduce the frequency of garbage collection by making it happen on
;; each 50MB of allocated data (the default is on every 0.76MB)
(setq gc-cons-threshold 50000000)

;; warn when opening files bigger than 100MB
(setq large-file-warning-threshold 100000000)

;; preload the personal settings from `prelude-personal-preload-dir'
(when (file-exists-p prelude-personal-preload-dir)
  (message "Loading personal configuration files in %s..." prelude-personal-preload-dir)
  (mapc 'load (directory-files prelude-personal-preload-dir 't "^[^#\.].*el$")))

(message "Loading Prelude's core...")



(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))






;; the core stuff
(require 'prelude-packages)
(require 'prelude-custom)  ;; Needs to be loaded before core, editor and ui
(require 'prelude-ui)
(require 'prelude-core)
(require 'prelude-mode)
(require 'prelude-editor)
(require 'prelude-global-keybindings)





;; macOS specific settings
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (require 'prelude-macos))

;; Linux specific settings
(when (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
  (require 'prelude-linux))

(message "Loading Prelude's modules...")

;; the modules
(if (file-exists-p prelude-modules-file)
    (progn
      (load prelude-modules-file)
      (if (file-exists-p prelude-deprecated-modules-file)
          (message "Loading new modules configuration, ignoring DEPRECATED prelude-module.el")))
  (if (file-exists-p prelude-deprecated-modules-file)
      (progn
        (load prelude-deprecated-modules-file)
        (message (format "The use of %s is DEPRECATED! Use %s instead!"
                         prelude-deprecated-modules-file
                         prelude-modules-file)))
    (message "Missing modules file %s" prelude-modules-file)
    (message "You can get started by copying the bundled example file from sample/prelude-modules.el")))

;; config changes made through the customize UI will be stored here
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" prelude-personal-dir))

;; load the personal settings (this includes `custom-file')
(when (file-exists-p prelude-personal-dir)
  (message "Loading personal configuration files in %s..." prelude-personal-dir)
  (mapc 'load (delete
               prelude-modules-file
               (directory-files prelude-personal-dir 't "^[^#\.].*\\.el$"))))

(message "Prelude is ready to do thy bidding, Master %s!" current-user)

;; Patch security vulnerability in Emacs versions older than 25.3
(when (version< emacs-version "25.3")
  (with-eval-after-load "enriched"
    (defun enriched-decode-display-prop (start end &optional param)
      (list start end))))

(prelude-eval-after-init
 ;; greet the use with some useful tip
 (run-at-time 5 nil 'prelude-tip-of-the-day))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")

(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))

(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")
(el-get 'sync)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)

  (setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
        python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")

(set-background-color "black")


(set-cursor-color "#5c14ff") 
(set-face-background 'hl-line "#001e3b")




(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)


(define-globalized-minor-mode real-global-auto-complete-mode
  auto-complete-mode (lambda ()
                       (if (not (minibufferp (current-buffer)))
                         (auto-complete-mode 1))
                       ))(real-global-auto-complete-mode t)


(package-initialize)
```

I do not see anything about transient in the init file but I still see

```
Error (el-get): while installing transient: el-get: make el-get could not build transient [make EMACSBIN=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_14 info]
```

*el-get-build: transient*

Where might this problem be coming from? Thanks.

Comment: Please show the minimum needed to ask your question. Don't just dump your entire init file here. Instead, bisect it to find the culprit, then if you still have a question post a minimal recipe to reproduce the problem. At least trim down the noise. This will generally help you get better help.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea what’s causing the error so I’m not sure what part to post. The error seems to be related to transient but I don’t see this anywhere in the init file. I’ve tried commenting out blocks but I get this error no matter what

Comment: `M-x describe-package` will tell you what packages required transient.  That might help narrow your search (it was probably `magit`)

Comment: You say you get the error no matter what. Does that mean you get it also if you use `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, then it's not "no matter what", and something in your init file is causing the problem. In that case, *bisect* to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by creating an early-init.el file and moving the following lines to it:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")

(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))

(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")
(el-get 'sync)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
```